# Datatables without using Gem

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatables

I'm trying to embed datatables plug-in into my Rails 4 App. I tried putting the JS and the CSS directly into the view. However, it doesn't work.The plain HTML works just fine in the view but it seems as soon as the embed ruby present, something happens.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

I've been troubleshooting and I thought all I needed to do what change the table tag in my view and add the appropriate CDN's like I did for the HTML. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here is a snippet for my rails view:

```
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Clients</h1>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Zipcode</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @clients.each do |client| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= client.firstName %></td>
        <td><%= client.lastName %></td>
        <td><%= client.address %></td>
        <td><%= client.city %></td>
        <td><%= client.state %></td>
        <td><%= client.zipcode %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', client %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_path(client) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', client, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Client', new_client_path %>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you receive any errors? Did the client data show up or just the problem of css?

Comment: Did you include datatables in your application.js?

Comment: @pyfl88 I'm not receiving any errors and the client data does show up but not like in the example with the toggles on the columns.

Comment: @MarsAtomic if I'm using CDN's do I need to include datatables in the application.js?

Comment: @M.TDavis Yes, you need it! Try to open your page in Firefox using Firebug and you should get the error that the reference to the css and the js is missing

Comment: @mabe02 It seem that when I change the colspan tag too  `<th colspan = '2'></th><th></th>` the data table shows up. However, using the default that is generated within the view doesn't allow the datatable to show. Any thoughts on the reason why?

Comment: @M.T_Davis I guess that the responsibility of defining the `colspan` should be somewhere in the .css files that you are including..

Comment: @mabe02 That makes sense, I will look into that.